# Can't checkout from visualSVN server through domain name

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I've done a good amount of googling, and I don't think my issue has been solved, but I'm sorry if I'm mistaken.

Anyways, I've set up a VisualSVN server on my main desktop. It works on my local network, and has been useful for jumping between my desktop and laptop when writing programs for school. It's configured to use https on port 8443.

I then wanted to connect to it if I have my laptop outside my local network. I forwarded port 8443 to my desktop which has a static IP (`192.168.1.111`), and am able to connect to it via my external IP (`198.46.172.XX`) with my browser, and I can check out repos with TortoiseSVN.

This is all well and good, but now I have a couple of friends that I've been working with on some of my assignemnts, and I want to get them on my SVN too. I decided it'd be more convenient to have a domain name. I registered a domain on Godaddy, and set it up to forward the domain to my external IP (`https://198.48.172.XX:8443`). After some waiting for it all to kick in, my SVN is now accessible using my new domain in my browser (`http://mydomain.info/`).

Now to the actual problem; if I go to check out a repo with TortoiseSVN, and try to use `http://mydomain.info/svn/myRepo/` I get these errors:

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL" and "Unexpected HTTP status
>   400 'Bad Request' on '/svn/myRepo'".

If I try to use `https` instead of `http` or add the port to the end of the URL, or both, TortoiseSVN times out.

**TL;DR**: I can connect to my VisualSVN server via new domain and web browser, but I can't check out any repos with TortoiseSVN.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm running out of ideas. Any help would be much appreciated, and if you need more specific info please let me know and I'll include it as quickly as I can.

Comment: "set it up to forward the domain to my external IP" - details, please. And DAV-related config of your VisualSVN server

Answer (score 1):

> If I try to use https instead of http or add the port to the end of
>   the URL

Because you have https (for Apache) on non-standard-port, you **must** at least use this pointers in URL: `https://name/path:8443` in SVN-clients.

Question about "forward domain to IP" still applicable - I don't know Godaddy's internals